# Honda Accord Coupe 1999 Overhead Lighting Keeps Blowing Out

Tags: honda, accord, lights, wiring

The overhead lighting keeps blowing out and the fuses blow out about every day. I have used 4 so I don't know where to start looking. All of the inside lights Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a sunroof that might be leaking?

Answer (score 3):

Check for a shorted wire. If the fuse keeps blowing, you could have a wire touching metal somewhere in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Possible bad ground wire/strap in that area.  Also could be a bad bulb socket.